# Jasmine (mocha) nested "it" tests

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jasmine, mocha.js

I was trying to test consequent create/delete of items (in mongoDB via mongoose).

The problem that creating is async and it returns ID of created item in callback function, I need this ID to deleted created item, so I tried the following code for mocha (in different ways) but it didn't work.

```
describe('Item Model', function(){

  it('should be able to create item', function(done){
    var item = new Item({name: {first: "Alex"});
    item.save(function(err, data){

      it('should be able to deleted created item', function(done){                    
        Item.delete({_id: data.id}, function(err, data){
        done(err);
        });
      });

    })
  });

});
```

Can such test be implemented in mocha or jasmine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would have two tests for that. One that is testing insert and one that tests remove.

Should look something like this in coffeescript

```
describe 'Item model', () ->
   item = ''
   before (done) ->
      item = new Item {name: {first: "Alex"}}
      done
    describe 'When inserting Item', () ->
        before (done) ->
            item.save done
        it 'should have been insterted' ->
            #CHECK HERE IT IF IT IS INSERTED

    decribe 'when deleting', () ->
        before (done) ->
            item.save (err,data) ->
                return done err if err
                Item.delete {_id: data.id}, done
        it 'should have been deleted' ->
            #CHECK HERE IT IF IT IS Deleted
```

Comment: It's a bad practice to answer JavaScript questions with CoffeeScript answers. I do love CoffeeScript, but not all JS programmers could read and understand it.

Comment: CoffeeScript isn't JS. Just as ClojureScript isn't JS. Just as C isn't assembler. However, this is actually a jasmine / mocha question, and you can write jasmine / mocha tests in preprocessor languages, so it should be fine.

Comment: the thing i dont like about this, it perpetuates another xmass tree of code... Your code is 4 levels deep.. and yet you are only describing a single nested test case...and everyone seems 'ok' with this..

Answer (score 4):

See this issue:
https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/438

Seems that the intention is to force tests to be de-coupled. While inconvenient and possibly requiring more mocking, this behavior is useful because it requires less re-testing and provides a clearer image of exactly what is going wrong.

i.e. there are 2 tests, test A and test B, where B is dependent on A.

Test A breaks, B therefore breaking as well. You fix what is breaking test A, but may now be surprised to find that test B broke either in the process of your fix, or for an unrelated reason.

When the tests do not rely on each other, you have better information and fewer surprises.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue and when I tried a nested describe/it structure it actually worked.

```
describe('Item Model', () => {
   it('should be able to create item', done => {
      var item = new Item({name: {first: "Alex"});
      item.save(function(err, data){
         describe('Item Delete', () => {
            it('should be able to deleted created item', done => {
               Item.delete({_id: data.id}, function(err, data){
                 done(err);
               });
            });
         });
      }); 
   });
});
```